# how to force client(winform) application to use NTLM when calling web services

Tags: winforms, security, iis, authentication, kerberos

I have a winform application calling web services hosted in IIS, by default, the client app will use Kerberose for authentication to IIS, and it failed for some reasons。 But the same app works fine at another PC(with different user login), and I found it is using NTLM by checking the IIS server event log.

is there anyway we can change the client app(winform) authentication type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`HttpWebRequest.Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) documentation, to restrict the request authentication to particular methods only, you need to create a new instance of the [`CredentialCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx) class, bind your credentials to the desired authentication methods and set it to the `Credentials` property.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried hosting the web services with Windows authentication? Then the consuming application must also use the same authentication to access the web service.